# Running JavaScript with a web request?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, httpwebresponse, nodemcu

**BACK STORY :**
Let me come from my problem, I need to update firebase database with Arduino so I used firebase-Arduino library but for some reason it will not compile Node MCU so my next way is a bit complicated that is I created a java script to update the firebase I just need to add 1 to the database so I don't need to update sensor value or anything so if I load the webpage it will update the value ,I thought it will be triggered with http request from Arduino but I was wrong it does not work like that.

**QUESTION :** How to run the JavaScript in a webpage with a web request from Arduino?

Comment: Hi RTZ, welcome to SO. Your question is not very clear to me.  Can you please elaborate a little on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: In general javascript has to run somewhere Browser, nodeJS or some other js interpreter. 
1)How do you run your javascript? 
2) Did you set up SDK like  described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @PriyankarKumar In short i need to update database with http request with arduino

Comment: @partizanos I have set up the sdk if i open the website it updates the database there is no problem with that now my question is how to trigger it with Arduino

Comment: The arduino needs to run javascript somehow. Did you install node js there ?

Comment: You don't have to do it with javascript btw you can jsut make a GET request with bash `curl` command for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have node.js installed  you can have something like this ([source](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)):

```
    const https = require('https');

https.get('your_url_here', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

But if you don't have installed node.js you might create the http request from bash commands like `curl`. This can be useful since you can make it run as daemon (run on th background every X minutes).
Let me know if you managed, something good luck.